# FTP date variable to grab ftp file

Tags: powershell, cmd, ftp

I am trying to write a script that will grab a file from an ftp site.

The issue I am having is figuring out how to grab the files that have dates on them. For example on January 1st we run mar2019. February 1st would run apr2019.

I am trying to figure out how to write something to automate this but cannot figure out how to grab the correct dated file.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

**u.ftp**

```
open ftp.site.com 
username
password
mget 'Name.Name.RENEWALS.MAR2019'
disconnect
quit
```

run with

```
ftp -i -s:u.ftp
```

Comment: this `(Get-Date).AddMonths(2).ToString('MMMyyyy')` will give the short name for the `current month plus 2`, plus the year number. right now, i get `Mar2019`.

Comment: you haven't posted a script! [*grin*] i have no idea where you would put the code in a script i have never seen ...

Comment: `u.ftp` is a command input file for the ftp.exe program. it aint what one usually refers to as a script. [*grin*] there is NO place in that _proprietary file_ for running powershell code. ///// you would need to write a PoSh script to modify that file by changing the `mget` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept to insert a variable into a template and
write that to a file is the same in batch/powershell.

As getting/formatting the date is easier in PowerShell a here string is used for the template:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\01\02\SO_54009396.ps1

$Month = (Get-Date).AddMonths(2).ToString('MMMyyyy')
$ftpScript = '.\u.ftp'
@"
open ftp.site.com 
username
password
mget 'Name.Name.RENEWALS.$Month'
disconnect
quit
"@ | Set-Content $ftpScript

&ftp -i -s:$ftpscript
```